# Does Opera Mini extreme mode behave depending on domain?

Tags: browser-support, opera-mini

Some websites like `https://google.com` are supported by Opera Mini extreme mode. I mean Opera Mini is a data saving browser. But, they don't save data in that website.

I've asked this type of question before on how to make my website work in Opera Mini extreme mode. There was just a single answer. I've read [Opera docs](http://docs.opera.com) and have to code my websites like that.

But, notice `https://google.com` in Opera Mini with extreme mode. I've copied the source code into a second site and these contain both same data. But, the second website doesn't behave like Google.

So, my question is if Opera Mini data saving is domain-based? Will it only work for Google and special websites. If not, why can't I enjoy those features in my own domain and site?

Comment: Please see the edit notes. This question is really pretty broad and off-topic for this site. We mostly deal with [operating and administrating websites](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, not development for particular browsers. You might be able to ask this over at either Super User, or Stack Overflow.